# WordPress: Convert Custom Post Type to Post including Custom Taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I need to convert a lot of posts from a Cutom Post Type to normal posts.
All of them have tags and categories based on two different Custom Taxonomies.

Is there any solution to convert the posts and keeping the taxonomies by inverting them to regular post tags and post categories?

I've found many plugins which can convert the posts. But all of them ingore the taxonomies.

Comment: Have you tried this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-switcher ?

Comment: Yes. The problem is, that there is no link to the posts. I will loose the connection from post and tax

Comment: Are you sure? Because post id is used to create the actual relation to term id.

Comment: you're right! I've added "category" and "post_tag" to the post type and switched the taxonomies. After that I've changed the post type with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/ worked well. thank you for your help!

Comment: Great. You are welcome! Please mark my answer as correct if you found it met your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding my answer here as well. You can use this plugin to convert the taxonomies https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/. Post and term relationships are added based on ids so the connections won't be lost.